# How to reference user-defined VBA functions in Power Query

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery

Briefly, the situation is that I have a set of custom functions defined for use in Excel, and a query in Power BI I would like to apply these functions to ( row-wise ) in defining a new column.

My ultimate hope is that I would be able to invoke a custom column calling on the functions with WorksheetFunction.'MyFunction' or some similar syntax. I realise I might just export the data, do the calculations separately and import the results in another query, but to me this seems like a crude resort. The lack of documentation seems to be confirmation of the negative, but if anyone knows any better the clarification would be much appreciated.

Apologies for the naivete, I'm quite new to the Power BI scene, but eager to learn. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use VBA from M code.

Comment: You will need to re-write your custom functions in M code (or R or Python since you are using Power BI) and add them as custom functions in your Query.  And no, it is not as simple as having an Excel-addin with all your functions that gets loaded automatically whenever you open Excel. Also, in Power BI there may be other solutions (report templates for one).